# Copy paste transaction emails but not working

Tags: magento-1.9, transactional-mail

I have edited the template for new_orders and it all seems to work nicely. The same part that required editing I paste into the template for new_shipments but the needed fields stay blank. I don't get it as its the same code as for new orders. Did the code somehow corrupt when doing the copy paste?

```
 <!-- [ middle starts here] -->
            <tr>
                <td valign="top">
                    <h1 style="font-size:22px; font-weight:normal; line-height:22px; margin:0 0 11px 0;"">Hello, {{htmlescape var=$order.getCustomerName()}}</h1>
                    <p style="font-size:12px; line-height:16px; margin:0;">
                        Thank you once more for your order from {{var store.getFrontendName()}}.
                        Your package has been shipped by Vendor <b style="text-transform:uppercase">{{var vendor.vendor_id}}</b>. 
                        You can always check the status of your order and shipment by <a href="{{store url="customer/account/"}}" style="color:#1E7EC8;">logging into your account</a>.
                        If you have any questions about your order or shipment please email the Vendor here.  <a href="mailto:{{var vendor.email}}" style="color:#1E7EC8;">Email Us</a> or give them a call at <span class="nobr">{{var vendor.telephone}}</span> Sunday - Thursday, 8am - 5pm.
                        You could also try the chat function on the Vendor home page. Click here to go to their home page.  <a href="{{var homepage}}">{{var vendor.vendor_id}}</a> In case you need additional support you may contact the customer support group of tee3sports.com. 
                    </p>
                    <p style="font-size:12px; line-height:16px; margin:0;">
                        Your shipping confirmation is below. Thank you again for your business.
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: It's probably because several variables like `{{var vendor.vendor_id}}` aren't available in that template. Since it's not default Magento can you tell me what module provides the `vendor` variable?

Comment: Its available and part of a market place module. But even the standard magento "{{htmlescape var=$order.getCustomerName()}}" can't been seen.